# How does Spring convert config values with units to natural numbers

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I can add these values to my config files:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    max-http-post-size: 1024MB
```

This has the big advantage that instead of writing `100000000000` I can use an easily readable number with a unit.
But what if I want to use this for my own config values ?

This for example does not work:

```
@Value("${server.tomcat.max-http-post-size}")
private Integer maxPostSize;
```

because it yields:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1024MB"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

I tried this on Spring Boot 2.1.6. I know how I could convert a string like `1024MB` into a number using my own code or some library but would like to use Spring Boots means.

Comment: You can also try this class: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html

Although you might need to upgrade your version of spring

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is that it doesn't.

The example property

```
server:
  tomcat:
    max-http-post-size: 1024MB
```

Is handled internally and will actually map to a String in the code. The string is then parsed and mapped to a long/integer appropriately.

So if you wanted to implement something similar, you would typically have to do something similar. Another common pattern for this is to have a property with the unit of measure in the name. e.g:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size-mb: 1024
```

This makes it explicit although you lose flexiblity.

EDIT:

Just took a quick read and it turns out that if you update to the latest version of spring (from 5.1+), there is a class called DataSize which should actually allow you to map a string like that to another class.

If you upgrade your version of spring, you should be able to declare your class of this type and add @Value

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html